# Show that $f(x)=0$ for a.e $(\lambda)x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$,and let $ f\in L_{1}(\mathbb{R},L,\lambda)$ such that $$ \int_{(-\infty, x)} f(t)d\lambda(t)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$ Show that $f(x)=0$ for a.e $(\lambda)x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here $(\mathbb{R},L,\lambda)$ is the Lebesgue measure space. Had it been the borel set $B_{\mathbb{R}}$, I would have been done since $B_{\mathbb{R}}$ is generated by intervals. I am confused with the sigma algebra. If I could show that $$\int_{E}f(t)d\lambda(t)=0$$ for every $E \in L$, then I will be through. But I don't know what $E$ looks like in the first place.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Just use the fact that any Lebesgue measurable set is "almost" a Borel set - in the sense that the two differ by a set of measure zero.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan why is that true??

Comment: It is something one has to prove - it should be in the textbook you are following.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thank you.